# How to use number flags in sed

Tags: sed

I have read sed info. In capture 3.5 :The s Command

There is a description:

```
The s command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:

number
Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.
Note: the posix standard does not specify what should happen when you mix
the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed 
upon meaning  across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction
is  defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and then match
and  replace all matches from the numberth on.
```

I do not know how to use it ,who can give a example.

```
echo a1 | sed -n 's/\(a\)1/\13/p'
```

the result is no different with

```
echo a1 | sed -n 's/\(a\)1/\13/1p'
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Provide an input and use a pattern that can match more than once and supply the number as a flag.

Comment: Yes, describe the problem you're trying to solve **with small sample data and expected output**. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "hi hi hi" | sed 's/hi/hello/2'
echo "hi hi hi" | sed 's/hi/hello/3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The number obviously only makes sense when there is more than one match.

```
sed 's/a/b/4' <<<aaaaa
aaaba
```

If there isn't a fourth match, obviously, no substitution takes place.